# DirectX, reference counts, and smart pointers

Tags: c++, windows-7-x64, smart-pointers, directx-11

I am building a game in C++ and for the sake of securing myself against memory leaks, I'd like to make sure I do everything properly from the start.

At the moment, I have a D3D class that contains all my direct3D stuff.

However, my Render() method will need access to the DeviceContext at some point. To get that, my D3D class will have to return the ID3D11DeviceContext pointer from within itself. This will mean I have another reference to that COM object without having increased it's reference count.

For example:

```
Render()
{
    m_d3d.GetDevCon()->DoWhatever();
}
```

Could I use it like that, meaning I never have to make an outside copy of the pointer? Would this be safe? Is there anything I can do to protect my program from bad things happening, such as potentially this:

```
Render()
{
    ID3D11DeviceContext* devCon = m_d3d.GetDevCon();
    devCon->DoWhatever();
}
```

I could see this would mean the reference count wouldn't match the actual number of references.

Essentially I want to try and avoid using raw pointers if I can. I want to get the hang of not just using smart pointers, but knowing WHEN to use them.

Comment: Why wouldn't std::unique_ptr inside your rendering class not solve what you need?

Comment: it might do, however my knowledge of smart pointers is that vague that I haven't the first clue about how to go about using them.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to prevent the pointer from being *seated*; consider having `GetDevCon` return a reference to the DeviceContext rather than a pointer.

Comment: so
ID3D11DeviceContext& cD3D::GetDevCon()
{
 return *m_devCon;
}
?

Also can you define "seated" for me? Terminology has never been a strength of mine

Answer (score 2):

For COM objects like Direct3D objects, you should use the smartpointer `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` (usable with the Windows 8.x SDK in all C++ apps including Win32 desktop apps).

`std::unique_ptr` is great for many uses, as is `std::shared_ptr`, but they don't work that well for COM objects.

The code below is 'safe' to use a raw pointer without increasing the reference count as long as you don't have another thread that could potentially release the `ID3D11DeviceContext` enough to be deallocated. It would be a strange program that would do that from a thread other than the one you are running your rendering on.

```
Render()
{
    ID3D11DeviceContext* devCon = m_d3d.GetDevCon();
    devCon->DoWhatever();
}
```

In other words, in a standard game loop of update/render/present, you don't need to create 'strong reference' (i.e. increase the refcount) just to render with it, and you can safely use a 'weak reference' (i.e. a pointer without increasing the refcount) as long as you have a clear initialization process whereby the device/context could only be destroyed and/or recreated at a specific point in that game loop (i.e. not in the middle of update or render, but likely as a response to a failed Present).

See [Smart Pointers (Modern C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx) and the [Direct3D Win32 Game Visual Studio template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx) for more information.

You might find the examples of various 'exception-safe' usages of smart pointers useful from [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/17/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games.aspx) article.

Comment: I'm trying to make it memory safe without hitting performance too much if at all. It's perfectly safe while I'm using it, because I'm a fairly sensible programmer, but I eventually intend to open this up to contributions from others and I'd like to set it up to make it hard to get wrong.

Comment: How fast would it be to use a ID3D11DeviceContext* directly in cMain compared to wrapping it in cD3D and returning it (dereferenced) from a method?

Comment: In all but the most trivial drawing cases, things like this are going to be dwarfed by the drawing time and other computations in your game. That said, you don't want to be incrementing ref-counts and then decrementing those counts in the same frame unnecessarily. Use ``Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`` rather than some home-rolled silliness for a COM smartpointer.

Comment: ComPtr isn't available to me, I am using the Windows SDK that comes with vs 2012. Every guide I read also seems to demonstrate that ComPtr can only be used for WinRT apps, when I'm writing for Windows 7

Comment: ``Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`` works perfectly fine for Win32 desktop apps on Windows Vista or Windows 7 or later with the Windows 8.x SDK that comes with VS 2012/VS2013. It has no binary dependencies and is fully inline--unlike ATL ``CComPtr``. Just use it.

Comment: If you are worried about accidentally using some other part of WRL, then use in your .cpp files: ``using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;`` rather than ``using namespace Microsoft::WRL;`` so you can use unqualified ``ComPtr<T>`` in your code--C++ best practice is to use fully qualified type names in headers and not using namespace statements so you'd use ``Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<T>`` for .h/.hpp files.  What you can't use on Windows Vista / Windows 7 is WinRT APIs which is the usual reason you'd use WRL in the first place.

Comment: Riiight well so far I've not been able to quite work out what I need to include and link to in order to be able to use ComPtr, any pointers (lol*) in the right direction?

Comment: ``#include <wrl.h>`` and you don't have to link to anything. See [this](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ComPtr) wiki page for some usage guidelines.